# How to destroy the admin session and the user session separately in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I'm currently working with an application where I'm facing an obvious problem. There are two major panels in my application one is the *admin* panel and the other is the *user* panel as obvious.

Suppose, the admin currently logs in into his panel and the same time some users on the *user* panel may have already logged in. What happens,  if I'm using the following code in PHP to log out and redirect to the *log in* page (when either the admin or any of the users logs out).

```
session_start();
session_unset();

if(session_destroy())
{
    header("location:Login.php");   
}
```

Let's assume that a user is logging out while the admin still logs in. The above code will destroy the session and consequently, the admin will also log out and redirected to the *log in* page.

I know session can be unset something like this `unset($_SESSION['something'])` but it's a tedious process to remember all the session variables used in the application as there are so many session variables have already been used in both the sides (admin and user).

Is there a way to destroy the admin session and the user session separately? I mean when a user logs out his session is destroyed that must not affect the admin session at all and vice verse.

Comment: You don't need to "remember the session variables", just use `array_keys($_SESSION)` and you instantly have an array full of every session variable's name.

Comment: *"The above code will destroy the session and consequently, the admin will also log out and redirected to the log in page."* the above code cannot cause that to happen, although maybe you have other code elsewhere causing it.

Comment: @chris:) But it's happening when I log in into the `admin` panel and the same time as a user and when the user (means me myself) logs out that causes the admin to log out and redirect to the log in page.

Comment: only because your application allows a user to be an admin at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sessions are independent between users. Just because one user logs out doesn't mean that every single session is destoryed - just the user's who logged out.

Comment: Why is it happening in my case when a user logs out, the admin who is currently working in his panel also logs out automatically and vice verse?

Comment: Are you testing this in the same browser (in other words, with the same session)?

Comment: Both admin and user are at the same localhost right now. Is this the issue?

Comment: No, I mean are you logging in as admin, and then logging in again as a user in the same browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing so with the same browser.

Comment: That explains it then. They are both the *exact same* session. Try it with two different browsers (or one browser but with the second user in a Private Browsing window)

Comment: I have already tried that a few days ago with different browsers where there is no such an issue but I afraid when I tried it with the same browser. I need not then modify anything in my application, I think. Am I right?

Comment: Well, think about it. How likely is it that a user and an admin are going to be logged in on that *same computer*, using the *same browser*?

Comment: Of course, I can understand what you mean. It was my incompleteness of thinking. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution - add a level to your vars so that admin and user vars are in completely separate sections, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['admin']['setting1'] = 'someval';
$_SESSION['admin']['setting2'] = 'otherval';

$_SESSION['user']['setting3'] = 'foo';
$_SESSION['user']['setting4'] = 'bar';
```

then, if the user logs out of the admin section, it's a simple

```
unset($_SESSION['admin']);
```

and **POOF**, all admin vars are gone.